# How to write protect a directory?

Tags: linux, permissions, access-control-list, directory, selinux

I have some directories and files that looks like this one

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 ss ss 4096 Oct  3  2004 backup
```

Notice the `.` in the permissions.

The user `ss` can not delete this directory.

**Question**

How do I set such write protection and how do I undo it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.` at the end of the permissions is *probably* not relevant here.  It indicates ACLs and/or SElinux attributes apply.  See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/230559/what-does-the-dot-mean-at-the-end-of-rw-r-r-how-do-you-set-it-with-chmod) for more details.

If the user `ss` cannot delete this directory it is probably because he does not have write permission on the parent dir of this backup dir.

Add write permission for user `ss` to the parent directory of the directory backup to allow removal.

Deleting a file or directory requires write directory to the parent directory because **that** is the file you are editing.

If user ss has write permissions on the parent directory and you are still unable to remove the directory check acls (using `getfacl`) and SELinux context (using `ls -ldZ`).

Comment: What does the `.` then mean?

Comment: The `.` means there is an SELinux security context a `+` would indicate an extended ACl.

Comment: SELinux is disabled. Could this still be a problem?

Comment: @Sandra: try it, and let us know it it worked or not.  If you are still unable to delete the directory update your question with the `getfacl` and `ls -dZ` output.

Answer (score 0):

```
getfacl backup
ls -lZ
```

This will show you SELinux contex and ACL. Maybe this will help you.